# Medir RTT em JAVA

Tags: java, socket, redes

Há alguma forma de medir a latência entre um cliente e um servidor em JAVA?

Pretendo criar um servidor proxy que vai redirecionar a requisição de um cliente para algum dos outros dois servidores, e uma das métricas para escolha do servidor será baseada também na latência entre os servidores e o proxy. E gostaria de colocar o código para medir o RTT diretamente na minha aplicação.